# Error "global name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined"

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have just installed Beautifulsoup using

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

It saved in the `c:python27\lib\site-packages`

I imported in `pycharm` using the following command

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When I am running it, it displays error

`global name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined`

Any idea what could be the issue here? Do I need to change import path to

`-> from bs4 import site-packages/Beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the interpreter located at `c:\python27` is not the interpreter selected by your PyCharm project.

In PyCharm you can check on the Interpreter and Packages by going to `File-->Settings`. Then, in the settings menu's tree-view, select `Project:<your project name>-->Project Interpreter`.

You can make sure the selected interpreter is, in fact, the one located at `c:\python27\`. (It's in the dropdown a the top of the page)

Or... you can keep the current interpreter and click the `+` icon on the top-left hand side of the screen, opening the `Available Packages` menu. Search for `selenium` and click `Install Package`.

Also, now that you're package-wrangling, it might be a good time to try using a [venv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I restarted. Must be something wrong with the pycharm itself.